# Getting syntax error for println in scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to run the following code but getting an error on Scala 3.0.0:

```
// saved as file Upper1.scala

class Upper1:
  def convert(strings: Seq[String]): Seq[String] =
    strings.map((s: String) => s.toUpperCase)

val up = new Upper1()
val uppers = up.convert(List("Hello", "World!"))
println(uppers)
```

```
% scala Upper1.scala
```

```
-- [E080] Syntax Error: /Users/Deb/Desktop/Temp/Upper1.scala:7:0 ------------
7 |println(uppers)
  |^^^^^^^
  |Expected a toplevel definition
1 error found
Error: Errors encountered during compilation
```

Am I running it incorrectly?

Comment: is it clear why u cannot use `println` at the top level? Should I give u more details?

Comment: That would help a bit more to understand why we can't use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the top-level, you can write only *definition* (e.g., `val`, `def`, `class`, ...) but not *expression* (e.g., `1 + 1`, or in general functional call).

Therefore, if you wanna execute `println(uppers)` during the execution, you can write the main of the program:

```scala
@main
def main(): Unit =
  println(uppers)
```